# Text widget is not getting removed in Tkinter code

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, widget

I have created a survey where I am calling a comment_box (text widget) when I ask an objective question and call subj_ans (text widget) box where I ask subjective question.

The problem I am not able to figure out that when I call display_entry() method the code is not removing comment_box.

I am sharing my code below which is definitely not of great quality as I am newbie.

Appreciate any help I can get.

Thanks a lot in advance.

```
        def display_entry(self):
            print("I am inside entry")
    
            for widget in self.q_list:
                widget.grid_remove()
            if self.comment_box is not None:
                print("removing cbox")
                self.comment_box.grid_remove()
            self.subj_ans = Text(survey_frame, width=50, height=6)
            self.subj_ans.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=4, sticky="e")
    
        def display_comment_box(self):
    
            self.comment_box = Text(survey_frame, width=50, height=6)
            self.comment_box.grid(row=3, column=0)
```

Comment: There is lots of code to look through, it would make it much easier if you could filter out only what is needed to be looked into

Comment: In display entry method:::  '''  if self.comment_box is not None:
                print("removing cbox")
                self.comment_box.grid_remove()   '''' the last line is not removing the comment box from the grid

Comment: You gotta edit the question out to include only important code

Comment: `self.comment_box.grid_remove()` is actually removing the comment_box Text box, and then `subj_ans` Text box is being created for subjective questions. **There is no Entry widget.** Both the boxes are text-boxes of the same configurations, so to know the difference between both of them, make one as Entry widget like `self.comment_box = Entry(s...`. What really is the problem, please clarify.

Comment: I have edited the question and code, please let me know if the problem is clear now?

Comment: I also want to use both as a text box widget as the content inside them is gonna be multiline

Comment: Since you have created a text box (`self.subj_ans`) with same size at same position, so how do you know that `self.comment_box` is not removed?  Try using different background colors for the two text boxes.

Comment: I know it's not getting removed because they are appearing next to each other with a small border bifurcating them :(

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I think I've figured out the problem. if you want to remove the comment box I think you need to do `self.comment_box.destroy()`. This completely removes the comment_box and then you can create a new one in display_comment_box. Does this work for you? If not, let me know!

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I tried what you suggested but its not even destroying the widget

Comment: Can you make a minimum reproducible example so I can do some detective work? Thanks for the speedy response by the way. Make sure to put the minimum reproducible example in the question

Answer (score 0):

@Saitama. You are doing wrong with the `display_entry()` function, Just called `display_comment_box` in `display_entry()` function.

Without button , `you can bind self.entry.bind('<Return>', ...` in other to saved all widgets.

Code:

```
class ......:
    def __init__(....):
        self.comment_box = Text(survey_frame, width=50, height=6)
        self.comment_box.grid(row=3, column=0)
        self.subj_ans = Text(survey_frame, width=50, height=6)
        self.subj_ans.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=4, sticky="e")

        def display_entry(event):
            print("I am inside entry")

            for widget in self.q_list:
                widget.grid_remove()
            if self.comment_box is not None:
                print("removing cbox")
                self.comment_box.grid_remove()

            value_entry = self.entry.get()
            self.display_comment_box(value_entry)
            self.entry.bind('<Return>' , display_entry)    

    def display_comment_box(self, data):
        self.comment_box.insert(END, data + '\n')

        return data
```

In fact, I didn't know about your `display_entry` function. You can suit yourself to modify. Usually I do in `irc` chat.